# Does it make sense to exit(0) after a call to execl()?

Tags: c, linux

Consider the following code:

```
close(channel_data->pty_master);

if (login_tty(channel_data->pty_slave) != 0) // new terminal session
{
    exit(1); // fail
}

execl("/bin/sh", "sh", mode, command, NULL); // replace process image
exit(0);
```

According to the documentation of `execl()`, the current process image is being replaced and the call returns only on errors.

But why call `exit()` after a call to `execl()` if the process image is replaced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does make sense to call `exit` after some [exec(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) function because they can fail (e.g. when [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) is failing). The  [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) page lists a number of failure reasons.

It should better be `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` or some other (non 0) exit code (conventionally a high exit code like 127 or 126 would be used for that usage, to separate failure of `exec` vs errors in the program it would run), and I recommend calling `perror` just before that `exit`. As [explained by PSKocick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45350424/841108) there are good reasons to call `_exit` (but his arguments could be reversed, one would want to run `atexit` and standard fflushs by using `exit` instead).

In your case, failure is unlikely, but imagine however if some other process has removed `/bin/sh` (e.g. the sysadmin making the stupid mistake of running `/bin/rm -rf .`  in the root directory, or in `/bin/`, perhaps in some other terminal window).

Still that `execve` could also fail when system resources are (temporarily) exhausted, e.g for

> `ENOMEM` Insufficient kernel memory was available.

And (in rare cases) this could even happen for `/bin/sh`;

BTW your `exec` usage would probably fail (with `E2BIG`) if (by mistake) `command` was a string of a million of non-null bytes.

As a general coding rule, all important [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) should be checked against failure.

Comment: What exactly does "failing" means in this context?

Comment: It means that the program you try to run could no be started, e.g. if /bin/sh does not exist, or it does not have the proper permissions to be executed, or the system disallows you to run the program (e.g. you have hit some system limit or policy that does not allow you to create more processes

Comment: @Shuzheng `exec()` family function can fail for a lot of reasons but the result is the same : the image of the current process will not be replaced and `errno` will be set. Therefore the code placed after the `exec*()` call will be executed.

Comment: *`fall`* or "fail" (in the first line)?

Answer (score 4):

Exec calls may fail. A common epilogue would be:

```
perror("Some eror message");
_exit(127); /*or _exit(1); (127 is what shells return) */
```

You would usually run `_exit` rather than `exit` here, in order to skip `atexit` hooks and `stdio` buffer flushes.

Comment: *`A common epilogue would be`* -- I think that's why using a comment for explaining the technique in the code is bad style. Remember that this will certainly be copied sometimes. ;)

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to call `exit` because you failed to `exec` the program in question and you typically don't want that process to hang around since it's not running what you wanted it to run.  Since `execl` only returns on failure, there's no need to check the return status.

In many cases, it also makes sense to print an error message to see why it failed.  You should also use an exit code other than 0.  A non-zero exit code is used to indicate an abnormal exit, and the parent process can capture that when it calls `wait`.

```
execl("/bin/sh", "sh", mode, command, NULL);
perror("command failed");
exit(1);
```

So yes, it makes sense to cal `exit`, but not necessarily `exit(0)`.

Answer (score 1):

> But why call exit() after a call to execl() if the process image is replaced?

As you said, `execl()` returns only on errors:

```
execl("/bin/sh", "sh", mode, command, NULL); // replace process image
exit(0);
```

In the code above, `exit()` is called only if the `execl()` call failed.

---

As [Jonathan Leffler suggested in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45350281/does-it-make-sense-to-exit0-after-a-call-to-execl/45350373?noredirect=1#comment77669369_45350373) it may be a very good idea to return a value other than *zero*, since zero indicates **success** and the code did indeed **fail** if the program's control flow ever reached the `exit()` call in the code above.

Comment: The exit status of 0 indicates 'success' — but the code failed.